# CP1250 (WIN1250) encoding in Debian 8 Jessie

Tags: postgresql, encoding, debian

I have to install WIN1250 (CP1250; pl_PL.cp1250) encoding to my Debian 8 Jessie, but I have no idea how to do this. I need this to initd Postgres database from external file (external company). When I try to initd this database I get error

```
#/usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin/initdb -E WIN1250 -D /usr/local/phsql/data

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "pl_PL.UTF-8".
        initdb:encoding mismatch
        The encoding you selected (WIN1250) and the encoding that the selected locale uses (UTF8) do not match. This would lead to misbehavior in various character string processing functions. Rerun initdb and either do not specify and encoding explicitly, or choose a matching combination.
```

But I CAN'T rerun initdb without specify encoding, because external app have to connect to database WITH encoding WIN1250 :(

Please, help me.

Comment: I don't understand why you **have** to do that. The encoding used by the client does not really depend on the encoding used by the server. But ISO8859-1 should be the same as WIN1250. You also need to specify a locale (`--locale=...`) when running `initdb` that is compatible with that.

Comment: When I try to connect to this database (initd WITHOUT any specify encoding, default UTF-8) with Windows client of this external app I get error in Postgres:

ERROR: encoding "WIN1250" does not match locale "pl_PL.UTF-8". DETAIL: the choosen LC_CTYPE setting requires encoding "UTF*".. STATEMENT: CREATE DATABASE "MMEDICA" ENCODING ='WIN1250'

Answer (score 1):

Okay I have a solution :)

Have to edit /etc/locale.gen and /etc/locale.alias and just add pl_PL.CP1250 to it. Next you have to reconfigure locales by dpkg-recofigure locales. And it works :)